# Remove selector not working

Tags: jquery

Why does the `:odd` selector not work when I pass it into the `remove(selector)` function? According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) it should filter the already selected set of items which in this case is the `li`'s.

```
<ul id='list1'>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
<ul id='list2'>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list1').children(':odd').remove(); // works as expected
    $('#list2').children().remove(':odd'); // does not work
});
```

---

**Result**

```
-One
-Three

-One
-Two
-Three
-Four
```

Comment: [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nX8s2/) worked for me. I'm using Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: @ThomasC.G.deVilhena: Switch it to jQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: @Blender: Oh! now I see. seems like a bug... +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually a bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13721

And was fixed 17 days ago in [jQuery 2.0](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/1b610266502490eab42a0b9ddfac2f93da0b0fe1#src/manipulation.js).

The problem was that it was checking to see if each element matched the selector:

```
for element in matched_elements:
    if element matches the selector:
        remove element
```

`:odd` only works in the context of a set of matched elements, so none of those elements individually were odd. Similarly, if you changed it to `:even`, all of them would get deleted.

Comment: Fast and straightforward answer +1

Answer (score 2):

The selector passed to `remove` used to be matched on the fly, that is, testing each element against the selector and removing it when matched, one element at a time. ([source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/03ab9b9f9061df1cf38fd6466c2241dfb2ae9cdc/src/manipulation.js#L165-L178))

This behavior was changed in [jQuery 2.0](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/), which now applies the selector filter before doing the removal. See:

[#13721: remove(“:nth-child(1)”) works differently than filter(“:nth-child(1)”).remove()](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13721)

---

(**edit:** correction on the resulting behavior explanation, @Blender is correct). In this case there's no matching as each element used to be checked against the selector individually.

Therefore the [`:odd` selector](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) would never match as all elements would be considered as at the jQuery object's index `0` (which is what `:odd`/`:even` checks) when tested against the selector. This explains why `:odd` never matches and `:even` would match all elements.